# Open Cursors Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

We have set the open cursors SCOPE = both to 1000.  We have a financial application that maybe 20-25 users log in to throughout the day that connects to the Oracle 19c database. In the application, occasionally we will see an ORA-01000 Open Cursors limit exceeded error.

However, when we look at this at open cursors current with this query we do not see any individual session anywhere near 1000.  This is the query I'm running for this:

```
select a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial# from 
v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s 
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  
and s.sid=a.sid 
and b.name = 'opened cursors current' 
and s.username is not null;
```

However, collectively we will see all the items in the v$open_cursors view to be past 1000.

```
select Count(*)
from v$open_cursor 
where user_name IS NOT NULL;
```

It looks like over 600 cursors are open under SYS, many of them I'm assuming are background processes.  They remain open under the cursor_type OPEN_RECURSIVE or something like that.

So to sum all this up, it appears that no individual session is getting close to our limit of 1000, but it seems that collectively we do get near 1000.  Which is the proper way to set the OPEN CURSORS limit so that no one session gets to 1000? What does making this setting for SCOPE=both do? Thanks!

This application, which I didn't create, does a very poor job of closing recordsets and other resources.  I'm sure some of the issue is related to that.

UPDATE: This issue happens after I migrated this application from the Microsoft ODBC driver to the Oracle ODBC driver.  It appears that the Microsoft driver handled cursors in a different way.  This application does a very poor job of closing resources but I don't have the liberty to make all of the changes necessary because it's pervasive throughout the system.  Microsoft is going to pull the plug on the Microsoft ODBC driver at any time in the future and they recommend getting off of it immediately.

**FURTHER UPDATE:** I've been playing around with various Oracle ODBC driver settings today and *found that the Statement Cache setting affected the open cursors in a negative manner*.  Even with 20 statements it seemed to make the number of open cursors skyrocket.  When I turn off statement caching altogether, I see a very manageable number of cursors generated.  Perhaps it's a bug in the driver because it's creating more cursors than I have in my statement cache.

Comment: The default of 50 is fairly low. Simply increase to 2000, then you are happy.

Comment: That's what I have done, effectively raising the limit to 2000.

Comment: `scope = both` means you want to change the paramater in both `memory` (i.e. *immediately valid*) and in `spfile` (i.e. valid after the next *restart*).

Comment: Check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64923547/409172) for advice on finding the cause of the open cursors.

Comment: The concern is that no particular session got near the limit when the error occurred.  Why would this happen?

Comment: Jon I was under the impression that the v$open_cursor view is not a good place to look for open cursors because it contains all kinds of cursors, including cached session cursors..  What does the gv$open_cursor view do that the other query doesn't?  I'll try this out.

Comment: @CharlesOwen To generate that error, one of the sessions must have exceeded the limit. These errors can be generated in less than a second, and then completely disappear when the session is closed, so they can be extremely hard to track down and you might need a continuous loop in a PL/SQL block to check for the problem. I'm not sure of the precise difference between [`GV_OPEN_CURSOR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/V-OPEN_CURSOR.html) and the other query, but all the cursors listed in that view count toward the limit so I'm not sure if it matters.