# Dump current open cursors when a ORA-01000 maximum open cursor error occurs

Tags: oracle, triggers, database-cursor

Our backoffice sporadically suffers from  ORA-01000 maximum open cursors error (The few time it happened was weekends when nobody work).

Is it possible to dump the details on open cursors in a table when such an error occurs so that we have time to analyse what causes it ?

This unfortunately has to be done on the Oracle side directly, as our application doesn't have access to the admin schema.

Comment: Ask the DBA to increase the limit. The default value (I guess 1000) is rather low.

Comment: So what happens at weekends? The app must be running some background jobs e.g. housekeeping routines , so the area of the code you need to investigate ought to be quite narrowly bounded.

Comment: @Wernfriend Already asked. Our request got denied.

Comment: @APC, quite more than housekeeping. Our main business is to execute batches. the very long/critical ones, are executed the weekend as it's the only time our dataset remains stable/consistent

Comment: If your requests got denied, then you may contact the DBA manager. I think it's their duty to provide a database for the business.

Comment: This question is kind of related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64144953/409172). You might want to check it out since there are pros and cons between my answer and Paul's answer.

Comment: @Wernfried the reason for their refusal is that we share that DB with other teams and we're already at the max they are willing to give (to not be unfair to others). So increasing the limit doesn't seem to be an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you are a DBA you can create a system trigger on server error, and capture what you need:

```
CREATE TABLE mylogtable AS SELECT * FROM v_open_cursor WHERE 1=2;

CREATE TRIGGER TR_SERVERERROR AFTER SERVERERROR ON DATABASE
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  IF server_error(1) = 1000
  THEN
    INSERT INTO mylogtable
    SELECT *
      FROM v$open_cursor
     WHERE sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');

    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END;
```

Or you can use monitoring software or write your own monitoring scripts to capture at intervals.

If you're not a DBA and they won't do the above for you, if you have the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` priv you can simply query `v$open_cursor` for your SID(s) at various times during your application run and you can probably see what's going on that way without using a trigger.

Make sure your application closes cursors that it opens. If `open_cursors` is extremely low, have you DBA increase it. But if we're talking thousands, there's an app design issue. No application should need thousands of open cursors.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to share this solution with my DBA team. I'll come back to you :-)

Comment: The only concern I have is that if the open cursors are at a max, this trigger may not be able to do its select on v$open_cursor as a result. Worth a try.

Comment: I'll let you know. The weekend in two weeks is gonna be busy,  there's a fair chance we'll encounter that error again. Hopefully this trigger will do the trick ^^.

Comment: Remember open_cursors is a session limit, not a system limit.

Comment: @BobC - Correct, but it can only be set at the system level. A complex and deeply nested PL/SQL application could conceivably reach a few hundred cursors in a single session, so there may be need to raise it from the default of 50. But most often it's an app design issue, simple failure to close cursors after they aren't needed any longer. Increasing it does increase the UGA memory requirement per process but only imperceptibly so.

Comment: @PaulW I think we increased the default to 300 these days, but customers still hit this limit. But my point was that constantly increasing the limit is just kicking the can down the road. Some effort should be made to determine the root cause of cursor leak.

Comment: That's precisely in an effort to determine the root cause of the leak that a dump of the opened cursors was needed. 
The problem didn't reappear on our side.

We did manage however to trigger an ORA-01000 intentionally, and the solution Paul proposed indeed worked as expected.

Thanks again.